# How to gracefully handle errors in apache kafka producer

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, channel

I have an ecommerce app where I'm sending a message to a kafka server every time a user adds something to a cart. I can send the message and consume it from a client, however, I am curious about error handling. Once in a while, my Go server fails because of a network error or some other reasons. Adding to cart functionality will be an essential part of the app, so I don't want kafka producer to fail that functionality or become dependent on it. I tried separate them by creating a separate function for kafka Producer and I think the `kafka.Produce()` function is non-blocking, so even if that fails user still should be able to add items to a cart. Here's a sample code (I put the full code for kafka part, but I trimmed the implementation of adding to cart for readability). Is there a way to quit from kafka function if something goes wrong or if it is longer than couple of seconds-timeout? So, the adding to cart functionality wouldn't hang or cause the server to fail. I'm not very experienced with channels and concurrency in Go, so I can't really tell if this could become an issue with this current design.

ADD TO CART

```
func addToCart(c *context.Context, rw web.ResponseWriter, req *web.Request) {
    cartID := req.PathParams["id"]
    var items []map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&items); err != nil {
        errors.Write(rw, 400, "Unable to parse request body JSON or invalid data format.")
        return
    }

    //MAKE SOME OPERATIONS AND SAVE IT TO DATABASE
    cart, jsonErr := saveToDB(c, cartID, items)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        jsonErr.Write(rw)
        return
    }

    webLib.Write204(rw)

    deliveryChan := make(chan kafka.Event)

    kafkaMessage("cart_topic", "sample-cart-event-message", deliveryChan, rw, rq)
    return
}
```

KAFKA

```
func kafkaMessage(topic string, message []byte, deliveryChan chan kafka.Event, rw web.ResponseWriter, req *web.Request) {
    err := c.KafkaProducer.Produce(&kafka.Message{
        TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topic, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
        Value:          message,
    }, deliveryChan)

    if err != nil {
        c.Log("error:%s", err)
        return
    }

    e, ok := <-deliveryChan
    if !ok{
        c.Log("Channel is closed for kafka producer")
        return
    }

    m, ok := e.(*kafka.Message)
    if !ok{
        c.Log("There has been an error obtaining the kafka message")
        return
    }

    if m.TopicPartition.Error != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Delivery failed: %v\n", m.TopicPartition.Error)
    } else {
        c.Log("Delivered message to topic %s [%d] at offset %v\n",
            *m.TopicPartition.Topic, m.TopicPartition.Partition, m.TopicPartition.Offset)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the send to kafka is async but you're, in effect, turning it into a sync function by waiting for a "success" message.

A couple quick options.

1: You can totally disregard the status of the async message [by passing a `nil` channel](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/7d2340912ba4a7a3437b775f304cba425d85ecd0/examples/producer_example/producer_example.go#L46-L48) as `deliveryChan`. Then you really get a "fire and forget" async model. It sounds like this may be what you are looking for.

2: You can run `kafkaMessage` in a goroutine by simply changing to

```golang
deliveryChan := make(chan kafka.Event)
go kafkaMessage("cart_topic", "sample-cart-event-message", deliveryChan, rw, rq)
return
```

Then you can keep your waiting for a message, logging, etc in that function. You can even add retries if you want! Be aware that in this case you can get a backlog of goroutines waiting on response messages / retrying / etc since you're essentially queuing up operations as goroutines. For most applications this won't be a problem as well as you're not continually falling behind in processing, but still - something to keep an eye on with monitoring!

There are lots of other patterns to follow here, but these are fairly low lift and give you a few options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @turtlemonvh ! For the second option, i think that's what i was doing except not using the go keyword. After using the go keyword with the same structure, the application hangs when user adds an item to a cart. If i remove deliveryChan from .Produce()'s params, then the consumer receives the messages but   in the kafka part, the program finishes before line 24 (the last if-else statement) . So i can't check if the messages are successful or not. Have any suggestions for that?